# JxBrowser onScriptContextCreated not being invoked

Tags: javascript, java, jxbrowser

I am trying to set up a Java Javascript bridge using JxBrowser. 
The `onScriptContextCreated` method is not being invoked and I am unsure as to why.

I have a browser embedded in my Java application and when I click the button, the window appears that says "howdy" but "hello" is never printed to the java console. I threw in debug lines in the `onScriptContextCreated` method and it is never hit.

Here is the Java code

```
    webBrowser.addScriptContextListener(new ScriptContextAdapter() {       
            @Override
            public void onScriptContextCreated(ScriptContextEvent event) {
            Browser browser = event.getBrowser();

            JSValue window = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window");
            System.out.println("Setting property");
            window.asObject().setProperty("sendNSCommand", new JSFunctionCallback() {

                @Override
                public Object invoke(Object... os) {
                    String command = (String) os[0];
                    System.out.println("Command from JavaScript: " + command);
                    return null;
               }
            });
        }
    });
```

And here is my sample web page

```
<html>
<head> 
    <script>
        function callMe() { 
            sendNSCommand2("howdy");
            sendNSCommand("hello");

        }

        function sendNSCommand2(x) { 
            window.alert(x);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="test" onClick="callMe()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this code sample works properly.
After I launch it in my local environment, it prints the "Setting property" line into the Java console. When I click the "test" button, the "howdy" dialog appears.  When I click the "OK" button on this dialog, the "Command from JavaScript: hello" line is printed into the Java console.